# Implement drag item to the screen edge feature

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-viewpager

I need to implement current tab change when the item is dragged near screen edge (left or right).

There's no problem with drag N drop feature and current tab switches. I just can't handle properly this event -  when dragged item is near the edge of the screen.

**How would you do that?**

What I tried:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_toggle_area"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/right_toggle_area"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
</FrameLayout>

<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ... />
```

The idea is to change current tab programmatically when the dragged item at toggle area.

But the event `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED` on that area never occurs since (I believe so) the `GridView` takes the entire screen and simply overlaps with toggle areas.

I've tried already bring those areas to the front when the drag start event is triggered. But that doesn't work for some reason.

```
FrameLayout toggleView = (FrameLayout) v;
        toggleView.bringToFront();
        toggleView.requestLayout();
        toggleView.invalidate();
```

*If anyone faced such problem please share your experience. Or perhaps there's another better solution for this. Please give me a hint.*

Comment: I posted my current solution. But still prefer to use drag areas mentioned in question. So please welcome if anyone has ideas.

Comment: so you don't want to drop and still change the tab?

Comment: Yes, I want to change current tab with `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED` event

Comment: which item do you want to drag and where it is placed?

Comment: I have 3 tabs with gridview at each. And the idea is to drag'n'drop one cell to the target tab. But the problem is to drag (not drop) on those toggles areas.

Comment: which cell are you talking about..is it in gridview area or separate from that area like the action bar or somewhere which is not going to change on dragging.....?

Comment: Seems like we're not on the same wave :) Dragged item is GridView's item (cell) which is simple linear layout with textview. Dragged areas are those FrameLayouts mentioned in question. And the problem is that event `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED` not occurs when Dragged item is overlapping with Dragged area.

Comment: now got it......try using empty view containers with view tag instead of framelayout.

Comment: could you provide sample as answer?

Answer (score 3):

I take it the parent of the three views (toggle areas and the `GridView`) is a `RelativeLayout`. First of all, replace the `GridView`, to be the first child of its parent. Leave the rest of the layout exactly as they are.

Secondly, in order to catch drop event with `View.OnDragListener` interface, you need to set the minimum SDK version to 11 in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. After that you can pass the listener to the toggle areas:

```
View.OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    // you can check for event.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED here 
    return true;
    }
};
FrameLayout leftToggleArea = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_toggle_area);
leftToggleArea.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
```

In case you still have problems, post more of your code.

Comment: There're no problems with the setup of drag listeners. I did exactly what you wrote here. The problem is event.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED never occures on toggle areas.

Answer (score 3):

The current solution I came to which works (more or less) is to use `TextView` nested in `PagerTabStrip` title as drag area. The biggest con in this approach is that those toggle areas are too small for some reason. ENTER event triggers only at those areas.

[image]

I belive this solution would be good with oldschool tabs. Therefore here's code. Might be useful for someone.

1). Parse `TextViews` from `PagerTabStrip`

```
private ArrayList <TextView> titles;

...

public void setPager(PagerTabStrip mPagerTabStrip) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mPagerTabStrip.getChildCount(); ++i) {
        View nextChild = mPagerTabStrip.getChildAt(i);
        if (nextChild instanceof TextView) {
            TextView textViewToConvert = (TextView) nextChild;

            if (textViewToConvert.getText().toString().contains(TabsFragment.TAG_MONITOR)){ // I take only few tabs 
                if (!titles.contains(textViewToConvert)) {
                    titles.add(textViewToConvert);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public ArrayList<TextView> getTitles() {
    return titles;
}
```

After this operation I have 3 TextViews that need drag'n'drop navigation.

2). Pass your list of `TextViews` to class where you implement `DragListeners`:

```
 public void setUpDragNDropTabMoves(ArrayList<TextView> views) {
    if (views != null) {
        for (TextView tv : views){
            tv.setOnDragListener(TabToggleDragListener);
        }
    }
 }
```

3). And the listener itself

```
 View.OnDragListener TabToggleDragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        TextView toggleView = (TextView) v;
        String title = toggleView.getText().toString();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                ...
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                int tabId = -1;
                //define which tab is destination
                if (title.contains(TabsFragment.TAG_MONITOR1)){
                    tabId = 1;
                } else if (title.contains(TabsFragment.TAG_MONITOR2)){
                    tabId = 2;
                } else if (title.contains(TabsFragment.TAG_MONITOR3)){
                    tabId = 3;
                }

                //send event to tab host fragment/activity and perform tab change to passed index
                //you may use EventBus or Otto for this. I used Local Broadcast
                BroadcastSender.sendMessageToUI(getContext(),
                        BroadcastSender.TABS_FRAGMENT,
                        BroadcastActions.TF_TOGGLE_TAB,
                        tabId 
                );
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                ...
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                ...
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```